# Why is dynamodb.update() is not updating the field in my Table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a dynamodb Table named "user_subscription", I want to update the **status** field from "ACTIVE" to "INACTIVE",

```
 const params = {
    TableName: "user_subscription",
    Key: {
      userId: userId,
      subscription_id: "abc",
    },
    updateExpression: "SET status = :newStatus",
    expressionAttributeValues: { ":newStatus": "INACTIVE" },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
  };
  console.log("params", params);
  try {
    dynamoDb.update(params, (error, data) => {
      console.log("error", error, "data", data);
    });
  } catch (err) {}
```

This code doesn't update the status field.

The response data which I get is:

```
Attributes: {
    plan_id: 'dkdkkd',
    subscription_id: 'abc',
    userId: 'ebef4c92-9fa8-4e1b-878f-d5753bb4042a',
    updatedAt: '2022-12-25T08:18:32.681Z',
    status: 'ACTIVE',
    createdAt: '2022-12-25T08:18:32.681Z'
  }
```

Comment: `updateExpression: "ADD statusss = :newStatus",` You misspelled status.

Comment: Updated, but still doesn't work

Comment: Is there any error or response you are getting after calling `dynamoDb.update`?

Comment: Not sure if the params are case-sensitive but try changing `updateExpression` to `UpdateExpression` and `expressionAttributeValues` to `ExpressionAttributeValues`. and also double check your `Key` values need to be matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Status is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html) in DynamoDB, I believe the code you shared should be throwing several errors, are you sure you are executing the correct code while testing?

To fix your errors, try these params:

```
const params = {
    TableName: "user_subscription",
    Key: {
      userId: userId,
      subscription_id: "abc",
    },
    UpdateExpression: "SET #status = :newStatus",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":newStatus": "INACTIVE" },
    ExpressionAttributeNamee: { "#status": "status" },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
  };
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that status is a reserved word.